# what does "type" in d3.csv does ?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, computer-science

I'm trying to understand reading external file .csv in d3 works with the **type**

I'm following Mike's 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1157787

I have read tutorial for reading csv, but I couldn't figure it out what type in this line actually does ?

```
d3.csv("stocks.csv", type, function(error, data) {
```

There are type function below

```
function type(d) {
  d.price = +d.price;
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  return d;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand this ?   `d.price = +d.price`  is that mean reading the next price ? or adding ?

Comment: This is not duplicate though, I title asking for "type" in .CSV I still don't understand how type involved in the read csv function. is it convert the data ?

Comment: Unlike JSON, CSV data is untyped, so all the values load as strings. `type()` provides an opportunity to parse/convert String values into Numbers when appropriate. `+d.price` is a shorthand way to convert such a string into a number. You can try this in your dev console: `+('42') === 42 // true` vs `'42' === 42 // false`. Or check out the difference between `'42' + 42` and `+('42') + 42`.

Comment: so if I use json , there's no need for adding type in there correct ? @meetamit thank you .